# Error al obtener los archivos de OneDrive - api | error "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow"

Tags: php, microsoft-graph

Estoy intentando listar los archivos que tengo en mí one drive sin necesidad de usar el login y me arroja este error.

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["code"]=> string(10) "BadRequest" ["message"]=> string(61) "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow." ["innerError"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2023-07-02T18:21:22" ["request-id"]=> string(36) "c3af2b23-8df5-431c-8d3b-ab4bb084ca26" ["client-request-id"]=> string(36) "c3af2b23-8df5-431c-8d3b-ab4bb084ca26" } } }
```

he leído en otras preguntas que la solución es cambiar el

*graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/**me**/drive/root/children*

por

*graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/**{users/userId}**/drive/root/children*

y no sé como obtener el **userId**

Cabe aclarar que la aplicación solo necesita mostrar mis propios archivos y no va a interactuar con alguna otra cuenta de Microsoft, adjunto código:

```
<?php
$clientId = 'TU_CLIENT_ID';
$clientSecret = 'TU_CLIENT_SECRET';
$tenantId = 'TU_TENANT_ID';
$resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com';

// Obtener el token de acceso de cliente
$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token";
$params = array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'resource' => $resource
);

$response = file_get_contents($tokenEndpoint, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params),
        'ignore_errors' => true
    )
)));    

$response = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response);

if (isset($response->access_token)) {
    $accessToken = $response->access_token;

    // Realizar la solicitud para obtener la lista de archivos
    $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children";
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers),
            'method' => 'GET',
            'ignore_errors' => true
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $files = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($files);
    // Mostrar la lista de archivos
    if ($files && isset($files->value)) {
        foreach ($files->value as $file) {
            echo $file->name . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No se encontraron archivos.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No se pudo obtener el token de acceso.";
}
?>
```